# Horizontal layout doesn't work after updating to Bootstrap 5

Tags: bootstrap-5

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CG0yT.png)I updated my script tags to bootstrap 5.  Here is my _layout file and the logon form I am trying to make work.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>@ViewData["Title"]</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/site.css" asp-append-version="true" />
    
@*    <!-- Original  -->
    <script src="~/lib/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/lib/popper.js/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/lib/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
*@

    <!-- jQuery -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <!-- JavaScript -->
    <script src="your-javascript-file.js"></script>

    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-GLhlTQ8iRABdZLl6O3oVMWSktQOp6b7In1Zl3/Jr59b6EGGoI1aFkw7cmDA6j6gD" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-w76AqPfDkMBDXo30jS1Sgez6pr3x5MlQ1ZAGC+nuZB+EYdgRZgiwxhTBTkF7CXvN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    

</head>
```

```
<div class="container">
    <form asp-action="Test" asp-controller="Home" method="post" class="form-horizontal">
        <div class="row">

            <label for="email" class="control-label col-sm-2">Email</label>
                <input asp-for="Email" type="email" id="email" class="form-control col-sm-6" 

        </div>
        <div class="row">
                <label for="password" class="control-label col-sm-2">Password</label>
                <input asp-for="Password" type="" class="form-control col-sm-2" />
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <label class="control-label col-sm-2">Remember Me</label>
            @Html.CheckBoxFor(modelItem => Model.RememberMe, new { @class = "col-sm-1" })
        </div>
        <div class="MyButtonContainer">
                <div class="container, text-center">
                        <button type="submit" asp-action="Logon" asp-controller="Home" class="btn btn-primary">Logon</button>
                </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

After updating to bootstrap 5, which I did to make some of the bootstrap controls work, all of my forms switched from Horizontal layout to vertical.  The attached image shows before and after results on one form.

I have tried to get the form to revert to horizontal but can't find the right combination.  If I have to change every form, it will be a lot of work.

I have reviewed the bootstrap doc and can't seem to get my form to work horizontally.  All of the inputs are 100% width, and the labels are on top of the fields instead of to the left.

Comment: 1) *The attached image shows before and after* - there is no attached image 2) Your HTML is broken. You have missing closing tags. 3) I don't know what you mean by *horizonal / vertical layout*. Please read [ask] and provide a [mcve] that allows to reproduce the issue (this includes a clear description of what errors you get and what you are trying to achieve).

Comment: Also you mentioned *reviewing the Bootstrap docs* but I can't seem to find anything in the docs related to the `control-label` classnames you are using.

Comment: SORRY.  I removed s bunch of stuff from the form for clarity and had unbalanced divs.  I fixed here.  I also attached the image (again).  Having trouble getting it to stick.  I thing its there now.

Comment: Nope. Your HTML is still incorrect + you still use classnames that *look* like bootstrap classnames but are not. And the official documentation has a complete example on how to create a form with inline labels and if you look closely, you'll find out that `col-*` classnames are not added to the form inputs but to a wrapping DIV element.

Comment: Interesting...I have been learning MVC for a couple of months.  I started with Murac's book, which is where I learned these class names.  They worked fine with the older version of bootstrap (commented out in my _Profile page).  I basically built numerous forms using this from the book.  Now, with Bootstrap5 everything seems to be different.  I did try using class="formfile" which I saw in bootstrap doc instead of class="row" but it didn't seem to work either.  Maybe I gave up too quick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using an old version of bootstrap which was references in a book I am using to learn MVC.  Apparently, the classes that I was using are no longer valid in Bootstrap 5.  I had to re-code all of my views using rows and columns as shown below and now everything is working.

```html
  <div class="row">
            <div class="col col-sm-1">
                <label class="control-label">Filter</label>
            </div>
            <div class="col col-sm-3">
                @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.GroupFilter,
                    new SelectList(Enum.GetNames(typeof(Golf.Models.Detached.GroupFilterList))),    new { onchange = "this.form.submit();" })
            </div>
        </div>
```